# How to now why my Browser say a lot of Error: The operation couldn't be completed (NSURLErrorDomain error -999)

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm doing a Browser, and I got a lot of times this error, does somebody knows why?

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1727260?start=0&tstart=0)?

It's an error defined in [CFNetwork](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/CFNetwork_Collection/_index.html), getting passed up to Cocoa where it gets a different name, which is what you're seeing. Check out the reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/CFNetworkErrors/Reference/reference.html). Something is canceling your request, and the library is letting you know, like a good library.

What is canceling your request? We don't know, because you haven't provided much info. I thought that link would point you in the right direction, but we both got nailed for too little info! So Google is your friend, Apple is your friend, cut-and-paste is your friend.

Start by tracing your use of the NSURLxxx functionality. You can set breakpoints around your code and step through the execution of your program to determine what may be causing the error. Find all places in the code where you're sending a request and put in a magic number, or something random to uniquely id each request, then see if you can use that to trace which is getting cancelled.

If you want to see the network traffic you can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) to sniff your LAN while you exec the app -- you will be able to see every packet.

Other than that there's not much that pops to mind other than to ask you for more specifics, maybe some code or a debug dump to let us know what's going on.

bye

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, psoft! We like answers to contain more than just links, that could go stale.

Comment: Thanks Michael Petrotta. Welcome to Stack Overflow indeed!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just saw that the error appears when the page takes to load and click the link again to reload the page, I mean that the error is not the problem, the problem is that you get stuck, waiting for an answer, too long. But I have no idea what ​cause it takes too time.

Comment: Could be anywhere - the link might be slow (try over WiFi, etc), the server might be slow. Sometimes I think my hosting provider has to boot a VM just to serve me a GET request. Best of luck.